# Cherrypy: Getting app config settings when starting with cherryd

Tags: python, cherrypy

I use the following command to start the script:

```
cherryd -c tiny.cfg -i tiny
```

But I cannot read the app config settings (database). What is wrong?

**tiny.py**

```
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld:
    def index(self):
        return "Hello world!"
    index.exposed = True

app = cherrypy.tree.mount(HelloWorld(), '/')
print 'app.config', app.config
print 'cherrypy.config', cherrypy.config
```

**tiny.cfg**

```
[global]
server.socket_host: "0.0.0.0"

[database]
driver: "mysql"
host: "localhost"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing your config to the tree.mount call as well:

`app = cherrypy.tree.mount(HelloWorld(), '/', 'tiny.cfg')`